# Poetry using wrong Python version and wrong virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-poetry

I am on Windows. I have made a virtual environment with Python 3.9.0 called venv in my current directory. I have activated it. If I run python --version I get 3.9.0:

[image]

This is not the system python, I checked with `py -0p`

The [Poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-your-virtual-environment) says that they respect existing virtual environments if they are activated, so I expect `poetry install` to use this venv.

However, when I run `poetry install` I get this:
[image]

It tries to use Python 3.11 which is on my system, it's not compatible with my project so it tries to find a Python 3.9 and... fails?

I try to tell it to use my venv with the `poetry env use` command but that instead makes a `.venv` directory:
[image]

Here is my `poetry config --list` output:

```
cache-dir = "C:\\Users\\Kevin\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache"
experimental.new-installer = true
experimental.system-git-client = false
installer.max-workers = null
installer.modern-installation = true
installer.no-binary = null
installer.parallel = true
virtualenvs.create = true
virtualenvs.in-project = true
virtualenvs.options.always-copy = false
virtualenvs.options.no-pip = false
virtualenvs.options.no-setuptools = false
virtualenvs.options.system-site-packages = false
virtualenvs.path = "{cache-dir}\\virtualenvs"  # C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs
virtualenvs.prefer-active-python = true
virtualenvs.prompt = "{project_name}-py{python_version}"
```

What is happening here? I just want to use my `venv` as if I was using pip, but with Poetry as a dependency manager instead. I have done this before on a different computer, I just don't know what happened here. I have tried with `virtualenvs.prefer-active-python = false` too

Comment: `python --version` isn't sufficient to confirm you're running the python of an activated venv. If you're in an activated venv, `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` should show the path (in case you've accidentally changed dirs), and `which python` should confirm if you're using that venv's python.

Comment: oh you're on windows, well you'll need the windows equivalent for those commands.

Comment: Like I said, I used `py -0p` and it showed it was using my virtual environment Python